# unable to locate a element thru Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a code to find cheapest tickets between two locations .I am stuck in the beginning of the code because selenium does not recognise simple input text box . here is the code .

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class orbitzsimpleTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
        dr.navigate().to("https://www.orbitz.com/");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("after threat sleep");
        dr.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='flight-origin']")).sendKeys("SFO");
    }       
}
```

I also tried to write the XPath using contains like

```
List<WebElement> s = dr.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'flight_*')]"));
```

No luck. It looks so simple but i'm struggling to go past this.

Comment: Please share your text box HTML first...

Comment: <span class="label">
<input id="flight-origin" type="text" aria-required="true" placeholder="City or airport" data-lob="FLIGHTS" value="Bengaluru, India (BLR-Kempegowda Intl.)" data-autoselect="touch" data-wizard-action="{"origin" : "$value1"}" aria-labelledby="flight-" aria-owns="typeahead-list" data-tooltip-id="typeahead-list" data-ta-key="flight_origin" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list" data-provide="typeahead" data-js-theme="typeahead"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can just get this element with `dr.findElement(By.id('flight-origin'))` or `(By.cssSelector('#flight-origin'))`.

And it's better to use 'smart' waits (wait for element to be displayed/clickable/visible) instead of sleep. Because it can be that 5 secs is not enough and you try to send key to the input which isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the reason why it was not recognising that element. It's because the flight tab had to be selected before it finds this text box .I was able to fix it .
Thank you so much for your input .